# CSS3 Transitions ease in for divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

My issue is that I want to make divs blur and active like  [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemBlur/) . I have managed to extend the code to divs instead of articles in this [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnu522qo/) but the problem is with the transitions (If the blur does not change please turn add jquery >2 in frameworks and extensions under the javascript settings,jsfiddle is not doing it). I want to implement the transitions that are in the first link.
They are the following

```
transition: 
        opacity 0.2s linear, 
        text-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out, 
        color 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I Hope This is What You Looking For 
https://jsfiddle.net/rominux/fm22qqdo/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.bluredDiv {
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
 -moz-filter: blur(5px);
 -o-filter: blur(5px);
 -ms-filter: blur(5px);
 filter: blur(5px);
 width: 80%;
 height: 80%;
 transform: scale(.9);
 transition: transform 1000ms;
  }

.activeDiv {
 transform: scale(1);
 width: 80%;
 height: 80%;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), 1px 11px 15px    10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 z-index: 100;
 transition: transform 500ms;
 }

.normailDiv {
 transform: scale(0);
 transition: transform 1000ms , opacity 400ms ;
 }
```

This is updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rnu522qo/2/